# Python Multiple Function Composition

Tags: python

So i have a homework question, but I'm not sure why I got it wrong / how it works.

```
once = lambda f: lambda x: f(x)
twice = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
thrice = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x))) 
print(thrice(twice)(once)(lambda x: x + 2)(9))
```

My ans: 25 -> 8*2 +9

Actual ans: 11 -> 2 + 9

What I was thinking:

thrice -> f(f(f(x))),
let new_x = twice(x)

thrice -> f(f(new_x)),
let new_x2 = twice(new_x)

thrice -> f(new_x2),
let new_thrice = twice(new_x2)

so afterwards I add in the `(once)` and did 
`new_thrice(once)(lambda x: x+2)(9)`

But answer seems to be that `(once)` nullifies the earlier `thrice(twice)` and am lost about. Would be great if someone has an explanation.. Thanks!

Comment: In general, it is bad form to assign `lambdas` to variables - prefer defining named functions with `def` instead.

Comment: The code provided outputs 11. Where are you getting 25 from?

Comment: I was supposed to write it on paper lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`once(lambda x: x+2)` evaluates to a function that applies `lambda x: x+2` to its argument. In other words, it's equivalent to `lambda x: x+2`.

`once(once(lambda x: x+2))` evaluates to a function that applies `once(lambda x: x+2)` to its argument. In other words, it's *also* equivalent to `lambda x: x+2`.

`once(once(once(lambda x: x+2)))` evaluates to a function that applies `once(once(lambda x: x+2))` to its argument. In other words, this is also equivalent to `lambda x: x+2`. This doesn't change no matter how many times you apply `once`.

`thrice(twice)(once)` evaluates to a function that applies `once` to its argument some number of times. (8 times, not that it matters for the analysis.) `once` doesn't change a function's behavior. No matter how many times you apply `once`, the final function only applies the underlying function once.

`thrice(twice)(once)(lambda x: x + 2)` thus evaluates to a function that does the same thing as `lambda x: x + 2`.

Now, if it had been `thrice(twice)(once(lambda x: x + 2))` (note the moved parentheses), then *that* would have applied `thrice(twice)` to `once(lambda x: x + 2)`, and the result would be a function that applies `lambda x: x + 2` 8 times.

Comment: oh I see! It seems I had a misconception of starting from thrice(twice) first

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you to figure out what is going on!

```
once = lambda f: lambda x: f(x)
twice = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
thrice = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x)))

# Created this one to help readability.
custom_func = lambda x: x + 2

print("once:", once(custom_func)(9))  # returns value
print("twice:", twice(custom_func)(9))  # returns value
print("thrice:", thrice(custom_func)(9))  # returns value

print("applying all those:", thrice(custom_func)(twice(custom_func)(once(custom_func)(9))))
# This represents the following: (((9 + 2) + 2 + 2) + 2 + 2 + 2)
# each pair of parenthesis mean one function being applied, first once, then twice, then thrice.

# If I've understood correctly you need to achieve 25
# to achieve 25 we need to apply +4 in this result so, which means +2 +2, twice function...
print("Achieving 25:", twice(custom_func)(thrice(custom_func)(twice(custom_func)(once(custom_func)(9)))))

# That is it! Hope it helps.
```

Comment: thanks for the help! But i wanted to understand why it's 11, not really to get 25 haha

Comment: Hmm sorry, I didn't get you wanted 11, because it was already giving 11 haha but alright!